# 2D image decomposition

Tags: frequency, wavelet, wavelet-transform, matrix-decomposition

I have a matrix and I want to decompose it into different matrices with low to high frequency limit. As I have noticed, it can be done using wavelet transform. I found something like the figure below for 1D signal and I want to do similar procedure for my 2D matrix using MATLAB. I want to decompose it to different matrices with low to high frequency components in different levels.

[image]

I used the matrix tool box, however, when I have problems with extracting the data.

How can I do this using MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the wavedec2 function.
There's a basic example w/ the function documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wavedec2.html)